# email field in custom-form using angular-directive gets vanished when i type in

Tags: angularjs, forms, input, angularjs-directive, html-email

I am currently learning an AngularJS and I came across the topic "Angular-Directives".So I planned to make my own `<custom-form>` directive.

**angular part**

```js
app.directive('customForm', [function(){
 return {
  scope: {
   userName : '@',
   passWord : '@',
   emailId : '@',
   telPhone : '@',
   address : '@',
   city : '@',
   state : '@',
   country : '@',
   pinCode : '@',
  },
  controller: 'FormController',
  restrict: 'AE',
  templateUrl: 'tpls/form.html',
  
 };
}]);

app.controller('FormController', [function(){
 var self  = this;
 self.username = "hemal";
 self.passWord = "passWord";
}]);
```

**HTML part:**

```html
<!-- index.html -- >
<!-- <div ng-controller="FormController as fc">
            <custom-form user-name pass-word email-id tel-phone country pin-code>
            </custom-form>

        </div> -->

<!-- tpls/form.html -->
<div ng-hide="userName == null">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userName"></input>
</div>
<div ng-hide="passWord == null">
    <label>Pass:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="passWord"></input>
</div>
<div ng-hide="emailId == null">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" ng-model="emailId"></input>
</div>
<div ng-hide="telPhone == null">
    <label>telephone:</label>
    <input type="tel" ng-model="telPhone"></input>
</div>

<div ng-hide="address == null">
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="address"></input>
</div>
<div ng-hide="city == null">
    <label>city:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="city"></input>
</div>
<div ng-hide="state == null">
    <label>state:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="state"></input>
</div>
<div ng-hide="country == null">
    <label>country:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="country"></input>
</div>
<div ng-hide="pinCode == null">
    <label>pincode:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="pinCode"></input>
</div>
```

Now the problem I am facing is:

1.As soon as I start typing in the email field of the form, the email field gets vanished.But, it is not the problem with other fields, they just perfectly fine.

2.If I set type="text" in the email field, instead of type="email"...it works...I just could not understand this behaviour.

So, if you could help me digesting this strange behaviour, it would be appreciative...coz directive is a very cool feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with **ng-hide="emailId == null"** 
It hides immediately because email id is not valid until you type complete email address. Documentation on null object says that undefined==null is true.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Use strict equality for comparison.

```
<div ng-hide="emailId === null">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" ng-model="emailId"/>
</div>
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/q4B6jvHvB84SqMYRAaIC?p=preview"

Comment: I have a doubt.I am setting ng-hide on "emailId==null"...not on ng-hide="emailId==invalid"... so even if I write  invalid emailId it is not null....why?

Comment: Look here documentation of null. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null . Documentation says that undefined==null is true. Created Plunkr for this check here. You will see undefined is printed on console until your input is not valid. http://plnkr.co/edit/q4B6jvHvB84SqMYRAaIC?p=preview

Comment: Well, that worked...all I needed to do was to use strict checking using "===". Can you update your answer , so that it can be useful for others, too?

Comment: Well that's great. Is really need to update the answer? Actually i'm new to this community and unknown to many things. I already created working Plunkr.

Comment: Yes, because correct solution is in the comments... your actual answer does not say about my problem, although it says about email validation using AngularJS.So please, update it so that it can be helpful to the community.

Comment: Thank you very much. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

@arun-shinde is right about the reason behind that behaviour, however you can avoid it using ngModelOptions too:

http://codepen.io/comakai/pen/JXJPrK

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <p>
        <input type="email" ng-model="a" />
    </p>
    <p>{{ a }}</p>
    <p>
        <input type="email" ng-model="b" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" />
    </p>
    <p>{{ b }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It is a nice workaround btw.One can disable the default invalid checking and put manual checking. +1